# Are there mistakes on the power armor table in fallout: the role-playing game core rulebook

Tags: armor, pricing, modiphius-2d20, fallout-the-role-playing-game

In Fallout The Role-playing Game, by Modiphius Entertainment, on page 137, it describes power armor and there is a table. I noticed that none of the costs make much sense (really, only 150 caps for the 4500lbs power armor frame, T-60 power armor pieces cost the same as the prototype X-01 pieces, etc), but what really confuses me is how heavy T-60 pieces are. According to the descriptions, T-60 was invented and was just starting to be mass produced and deployed before the bombs fell, but X-01 was still in prototype. For some reason T-45, T-51, and X-01 all have similar weights (all under 200lbs for a chest peice, for example), but T-60 pieces are all 700lbs+ (750 for a chest piece).

**Is this a mistake?** **Is it possible that they got the tables backwards, and switched weight and cost? Even so, why would T-60 cost so much more than the better prototype X-01 armor?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received the following e-mail from Modiphius which answers the first part of my question:

> Good morning,
>
> Thanks for your email.  ​
>
> - On Page 137 Swap Weight and Cost columns for all power armor entries. ​We are awaiting a clarification of the Super Mutant query.
>   My understanding is that a Super Mutant can only wear raider armor if
>   it is made to fit, but I've not much experience with this game and
>   will seek clarification for you.
>
> Kind regards and happy new year,
> Chris Dann Customer Service Representative Modiphius Entertainment Ltd

Multiple emails and form posts later, I finally got an answer to the second part of the question on the errata form:

> Modiphius-Nathan Modiphius Staff 3h It’s… complex.
>
> The values listed are accurate to Fallout 4, and that’s where they
> were derived from. In that sense, there’s no error…
>
> …but the values given for the X-01 armour in FO4 are essentially a
> token value, not intended to actually be used. Those pieces won’t
> appear in shops, but only found in the world through exploration, so
> you’d never be able to buy them for that price.
>
> So, essentially, it isn’t a mistake but it is lacking context.

This makes sense in that in Fallout 4 they had to give it some sort of value in case you tried to sell it or something, but its not intended to be bought. Likewise in the TTRPG it should probably be considered something that cannot be bought.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you are correct about the cost and weight being mislabeled and swapped. Undoing that would match the beta version of the tables. This change is not listed in the only [errata](https://www.modiphius.net/pages/falloutrpg_download) available. A poster also brings this up in a Modiphius forum post for errata (found [here](https://forums.modiphius.com/t/faq-and-errata-thread/14660/12)), but no official answer or acknowledgment was ever made I can see. The poster ALSO questioned the difference in cost between T60 and X01.

Comment: thank you. I contacted them via e-mail and they have clarified cost and weight is swapped, but they neglected to answer the second part. I will wait for clarification